# How do I manipulate a file that is named - (i.e. dash)?

Tags: linux, filenames

I have a file named `-`

I don't know where it came from, but I would like to look inside it to find out more about it. However, all of the Linux commands think I'm referring to standard input or they just give me an error message when I use `-` or `\-` or `$'-'`.

```
tail -
tail \-
tail $'-'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use a representation of the filename that isn't literally `-`. For example:

```
tail ./-
```

(where the `./` explicitly references the current directory).

Incidentally, this is also the easiest way to prevent filenames from being interpreted as options (e.g., to ensure that a file named `-f` isn't interpreted as an option, use `./-f` instead).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls -i
```

You should see the file's inode nummber:

```
10833498 -
```

Then

```
find . -inum 10833498 -exec tail '{}' \;
```

This finds the file with the inum and executes `tail` on it.

Comment: Another way might be to move everything but the `-` file out of the directory, and then tab complete the command.